# Why does "Brave New World" change perspective so many times in the third chapter?

Tags: brave-new-world

I recall that in *Brave New World*, the perspective changes rapidly between characters, sometimes as little as a single line of text is given then the perspective changes to someone else entirely.  Why was that done?

Comment: https://www.shmoop.com/brave-new-world/narrator-point-of-view.html

Comment: I honestly don't get the question. Can you clarify it?

Comment: This is a question that would be better asked at either writing.stackexchange.com or literature.stackexchange.com, dealing as it does with writing technique more than any science fictional content of the story.

Comment: @C.Koca: in the beginning, there is a few pages of very fast changes of point of view.  The book switches between several characters in several locations, sometimes dwelling on a single character for a sentence or two before changing entirely.  It's a unique thing that I'd never seen in print before

Comment: This question is now being discussed [on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11833/36526).

Comment: I've cast the final close vote. This doesn't appear to be about sci-fi, it appears to be about writing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The goal is to get as much information to the reader about the society as possible. So we hear from a lot of people in many areas, all supplying a bit more info.

In films, this would be like the opening that shows many people in rapid succession, each doing their own thing, all illuminating the world you're seeing.

A montage in print, effectively.